# append blanks to named list r

Tags: r, list, named

I have a codex with which I am trying to decode survey data. Unfortunately, in this survey data there are sometimes blank values and NA's which are not represented in the codex. My first thought to try and fix this is to append the codex, so that every question list has a placeholder for blanks and NA's, so that those values can still be passed through when decoding. I wanted to create a function like

```
blanks<-function(df,question){  
    df[[question]][[" "]]<-"blank"  
}
```

So that way I could run an lapply and tack on the value "blank" named as " " to every list within the codex. So instead of it being

```
codex$question1  
$'0'  
[1] "No"  
$'1'  
[1] "Yes"
```

We could have it read

```
codex$question1  
$'0'  
[1] "No"  
$'1'  
[1] "Yes"  
$' '  
[1] " "
```

I would then do the same process for NA's, and anything else I run into. Obviously this is not working, so I would love a way to make it work. This might not be the best way to solve the problem, so if there is a better way to go about this, I will accept an answer for that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `append` to append a list with one element:

```
list1 <- list(`0` = "No", `1` = "Yes")
append(list1, list(` ` = " "))
```

**Output:**

```
$`0`
[1] "No"

$`1`
[1] "Yes"

$` `
[1] " "
```

I would recommend against naming your list elements with blank though. Name it `blank` or something that follows standard naming conventions.